# maintenance mode on root avoid addon domains

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, addon-domain

**Problem 1**

It is little difficult but i have 3+ addon domain and their folders are in the root..
So example

```
www/index.php   ROOTSITE.COM
www/example.com/index.php example.COM
www/example2.com/index.php example2.COM
```

Remember the above example.com and example2.com is folders inside mains

So when i put the ROOTSITE.COM to maintenance mode.. by using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^11\.111\.111\.111
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://rootsite.com/maintenance.html [R=307,L]
```

It diverst example.com example1.com to root.com/maintanance.html
Kindly tell a way to avoid making example sites to non maintanance mode.. 
Just like that i do not want any .htaccess rules on the root to affect the addon domain (in the folders)

**Problem 2**

Also other thing
I need some pre made count down timer (in hours:min:sec) when site goes under maintenance mode... 
After the countdown ends it must divert to rootsite.com.... can it also change .htaccess? i mean when the count down ends it must change the rule of the .htaccess to remove rule of maintanance mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem 1

`.htaccess` applies to all physical subdirectories, regardless of the virtual host.

**Solution 1**:

Create `www/example.com/.htaccess` containing:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

This will override any rewriting rules in higher-level directories.

**Solution 2**:

Don't put maintenance rewriting rules in `.htaccess`. Instead, put them directly in the `<VirtualHost>` section in the configuration file of your root site.

---

#### Problem 2

Put a condition on your rule based on the current date using the [date variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). E.g.

```
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}-%{TIME_MON}-%{TIME_DAY}T%{TIME_HOUR} \
            2011-02-18T(09|1.|20)   # 9 am to 9 pm today
```

This constructs a string of the current date and hour from the `TIME_*` variables, e.g. `2011-02-18T15` (this is a prefix of the date in [ISO format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)). You can construct a longer string including minutes and seconds if you need the granularity.

The regex matches the number range 9 to 20, so it will match times from 09:00:00 to 20:59:59, i.e., 9 am to 9 pm.

Add this condition next to your other two `RewriteCond` directives and the rule will only be active in a certain time range.

Comment: Hey thanks for the info...I would also like to know more about the solution two..? also the can u atleast give a example of the TIME condition in .htaccess with my situation? if it is possible

Comment: i mean 2011-02-18T(09|1.|20)   # 9-21 today
here i don't understand what is (09|1.|20) exactly ? in description. I know it is time but is it ? 9:21 am ? pm etc  1. ? what is that 20 is minute or sec ?